# Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0 (in VSCode/NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I will answer this question, just wanted to document for anyone else who gets it.

I was running VSCode where I setup F5 to run the current file.

I was doing a first time call to AWS/Translate service, so of course I assumed that was the problem, but it was not.

I had a launch.json file like this, so when I press F5 it would run the current file:

```
 {
     "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
         {
           "type": "node",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Launch Current Opened File",
           "program": "${file}"
         }
       ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a program, and I thought I called it testTranslation.js, but I mistakenly named it testTranslation.json.

It turns out that if you press F5 on a JSON file, it will validate the file and show you if it has any JSON errors.

I kept changing the code in that file until I had nothing left but:

```
console.log("Hello");
```

and I was still getting the error.

Finally I compared to another test program, and noticed the file extension as .json and not .js.  So I just renamed the file.

Such a stupid mistake, but it leads to a more confusing error.
Would be nice if it said something like "You cannot execute a JSON file..."

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while trying to execute single mocha test (current file) and forgot to switch back to the mocha script after changing the `launch.json`.

In case anyone has a similar situation.